# Find address of a contract before deployment in Hardhat and Ethers.js

Tags: nodejs, ethers.js, hardhat

I have 2 contracts which take each other's addresses as constructor arguments. Here's the pseudocode,

```
constructor A(address B)
constructor B(address A)
```

I am deploying contracts using

```js
const Contract = await ethers.getContractFactory(contractName)
const contract = await Contract.deploy(...args)
await contract.deployed()

console.log(contract.address) // I want to find address before, not after deployment
```

How to find the contract address before deployment?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`@ethersproject/address` provides a `getContractAddress()` function to find future deployment address.

```js
const { ethers } = require('hardhat')
const { getContractAddress } = require('@ethersproject/address')

async function main() {
  const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners()

  const transactionCount = await owner.getTransactionCount()

  const futureAddress = getContractAddress({
    from: owner.address,
    nonce: transactionCount
  })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Contract addresses are deterministic and need the deployer address and nonce to pre-compute it.

You can use the following code to determine the contract address before deployment.

```
const rlp = require('rlp');
const keccak = require('keccak');
const web3 = require('web3')

const encodedData = rlp.encode([
  '0x6c4465dc4dc3466c5736142ce8e12917a1e22c4', // address from which contract is to be deployed
  web3.utils.toHex(4) // hex encoded nonce of address that will be used for contract deployment
]);

const contractAddress = `0x${keccak('keccak256').update(encodedData).digest('hex').substring(24)}`
console.log({contractAddress}
```

**But** I will recommend adding a method in the second contract and update the contract address later. Make sure that the function is callable only once, this will be a more reliable approach.

Sample code:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.8;

contract A {
    
    address b;
    
    function addSecondaryContract(address _b) public /* onlyOwner */ {
        require(b != address(0), "contract already added");
        b = _b;
    }
    
}

contract B {
    address a;
    
    constructor(address _a) public{
        a = _a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've found a helper function from Ethers which finds the future address idiomatically.

Comment: @secretshardul what was the helper function?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [**Prashant**](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/3446/prashant-prabhakar-singh)'s answer, I created [**Soladd**](https://soladd.vercel.app/) -- a web tool for finding **smart contract address before deployment**, just based on wallet address -- where nonce is fetched from chain but can also be set manually, if required.

[image]